# How do you show all the posts you've liked from one blog only from Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

I can see all the posts I've liked, but I want to see all the likes just from one of my favorite blogs I subscribe to.

There are lots of tools for managing *my* blog, but this is for a blog I'm subscribed to that I want to just show all the recipes from that I've liked.

I can see how to [filter by type](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/40794) and there might be some on Yahoo Pipes but I'm not seeing anything specifically.

There might be a solution using the Tumblr API as well but again, not seeing anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you are keen enough to get into the API, you could use the [/user/likes](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#m-ug-likes) function to grab all of your likes ([the last 1000](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/tumblr-api/exUSE_ySM1g/discussion) anyway) and then loop through them to filter out the ones that come from the blog you are interested in.